# The import com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use spark-sql java API to connect cassandra.
Below is jar i am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Trying to save an rdd to Cassandra table.

When I try to import 
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;

Its giving an error "The import com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil cannot be resolved"

What else I need to add in my pom.xml ?
Is there any spark-cassandra-connector documentation for Java 8 API ?

I am referring to this sample , to proceed in Java

https://gist.github.com/jacek-lewandowski/278bfc936ca990bee35a

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [following dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.3.1) instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In your example, the groupId isn't correct...

All documentation for Spark Connector is in the [repository](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc).

Comment: got you , In scala     vals_df.drop(col("lastStagedTs")).filter(col("BENCHMARK_TYPE_CODE") === "PERCENTILE_50")     this filtering was working fine ... now in Java this wont work as col()  is not defined.   I imported  import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;    still the "col" function not recognized , how to fix it ?

Comment: yes i have read this https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md  but not really helpful as most of the stuff in scala , for Java this is not descriptive .  Ex df .filter(col("BENCHMARK_TYPE_CODE").equals("PERCENTILE_50")) gives "The method filter(boolean) is undefined for the type Column"    ,